# Gnuplot plot Matrix over Matrix

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file which has lots of matrizes.

```
y [m]
0.000000e+00    1.751220e-04    3.499253e-04    5.240956e-04    6.974406e-04
8.698938e-04    1.041423e-03    1.211997e-03    1.381576e-03    1.550104e-03
1.717548e-03    1.883899e-03    2.049140e-03    2.213239e-03    2.376164e-03
2.537870e-03    2.698285e-03    2.857244e-03    3.014375e-03    3.168647e-03

temperature [K]
2.981500e+02    2.981482e+02    2.981463e+02    2.981445e+02    2.981426e+02
2.981407e+02    2.981388e+02    2.981368e+02    2.981349e+02    2.981328e+02
2.981308e+02    2.981286e+02    2.981264e+02    2.981241e+02    2.981218e+02
2.981192e+02    2.981166e+02    2.981138e+02    2.981108e+02    2.981075e+02
```

I want to plot temperature of y. How can i do it using gnuplot?

Comment: Do you want a 2D plot with y values on the abscissae and the corresponding temperature (same i,j in second matrix) on the ordinates? How comes your matrices have different number of lines?

Comment: That is exactly what i want. The matrices have 100+ entries so i just copied a few. I will edit it to make it consistent

Comment: The short answer is that you can't (directly) do it. Gnuplot combines only data from the same line when tracing a point. You'll have to pre-process the file, either with gnuplot (it will be a hack), or with some other software (the linux command `paste` would do). (Or change the code that outputs these files)

Answer (score 0):

One possible gnuplot "hack" for this would be the following (awkward but not too ugly).

***Edit:** simplified and shortened solution*

Works for gnuplot>=5.0.1 (no idea why it doesn't work for 5.0.0). Not sure, if there is or what would be the length limit for the string `mat2` for large matrices.

**Data:**

`SO40490348_1.dat`

```
# TestMatrix1.dat
# temperature [K]
2.981500e+02    2.981482e+02    2.981463e+02    2.981445e+02    2.981426e+02
2.981407e+02    2.981388e+02    2.981368e+02    2.981349e+02    2.981328e+02
2.981308e+02    2.981286e+02    2.981264e+02    2.981241e+02    2.981218e+02
2.981192e+02    2.981166e+02    2.981138e+02    2.981108e+02    2.981075e+02
```

`SO40490348_2.dat`

```
# TestMatrix2.dat
# y [m]
0.000000e+00    1.751220e-04    3.499253e-04    5.240956e-04    6.974406e-04
8.698938e-04    1.041423e-03    1.211997e-03    1.381576e-03    1.550104e-03
1.717548e-03    1.883899e-03    2.049140e-03    2.213239e-03    2.376164e-03
2.537870e-03    2.698285e-03    2.857244e-03    3.014375e-03    3.168647e-03
```

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.1, June 2015)

```
### plot two matrices in two files against each other
reset session

FILE1 = "SO40490348_1.dat"
FILE2 = "SO40490348_2.dat"

mat2 = ''
stats FILE2 matrix u (N=$1+1, mat2=mat2.' '.sprintf("%.6e",$3),0) nooutput
set key noautotitle

plot FILE1 matrix u (i=int($2*N+$1+1),$3):(real(word(mat2,i))) w p pt 7
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]