# Gnuplot set matrix dimension

Tags: matrix, gnuplot

I have a datafile contains two 101*101 matrix of float numbers, one is data and the other is error.
It looks like this

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
10381.8 0 0 3462.03 10341 0 6889.64
6919.26 6916.64 3459.49 10349.8 13781.3 6887.57 24157.2
3459.66 0 24158.9 13792.6 3433.65 27579.4 24117.4
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# Errors [Positon_sample/samp_psd.txt] I_err:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4892.66 4890.8 3459.49 5975.49 6890.64 4870.25 9130.63
3459.66 0 9131.25 6896.32 3433.65 9750.84 9115.54
3464.99 4888.97 5972.77 11419.1 7713.44 8438.29 9093.38
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Now I would like to only plot the first matrix.
I use "plot 'E:\samp_psd.txt' matrix with image"
But the program corrupt...
It seems that I should set the dimension of the matrix,

My case is a little similar like this
[Gnuplot plot Matrix over Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490348/gnuplot-plot-matrix-over-matrix)

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the two matrices with two empty lines like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
10381.8 0 0 3462.03 10341 0 6889.64
6919.26 6916.64 3459.49 10349.8 13781.3 6887.57 24157.2
3459.66 0 24158.9 13792.6 3433.65 27579.4 24117.4
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0


# Errors [Positon_sample/samp_psd.txt] I_err:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4892.66 4890.8 3459.49 5975.49 6890.64 4870.25 9130.63
3459.66 0 9131.25 6896.32 3433.65 9750.84 9115.54
3464.99 4888.97 5972.77 11419.1 7713.44 8438.29 9093.38
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Then you can access a single matrix with the `index` command like this:

```
plot "samp_psd.txt" index 0 matrix with image
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Without empty lines it also works. Really appreciate!